# "I'd be a * if anything" meaning

Tags: meaning

What does "I'd be a * if anything" mean exactly?

Examples:

[#1](http://nvnews.net/vbulletin/showpost.php?s=c7350ecea3e30e5b354eb0c7c53846a7&p=2449203&postcount=14):

> Let's see, I bought a Phenom 1
>   motherboard, and two Phenom II
>   motherboards recently. Can't remember
>   how many between 486 and the FXs I
>   bought. I've probably owned more AMD
>   motherboards than Intel, so
>   personally, **I'd be a fanboy of AMD
>   if anything**.

[#2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0758212666):

> He didn't know me personally and just
>   assumed things and I felt more like
>   **I'd be a slave than a team member if
>   anything**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps if it were to be rephrased it would make more sense to you:

> If you were to call me anything, you would call me X.

The first example sounds like a retort from somebody who had just been accused of being an "Intel fanboy" (or pick a motherboard or video card brand to substitute for Intel) because he (or she) had just pointed out some amazing feature of a new piece of kit.

The second sounds like someone who is a *team member* on paper, or at least in theory, whose input isn't welcome and whose *contributions* amounted to little more than carrying out menial tasks. It's another way of saying something like "team member indeed!"

Comment: Alternatively, *If I had to choose…*.

Answer (score 1):

This figure of speech is used in response to a statement the speaker disagrees with. It means that the speaker doesn't really think the statement applies, and even if it did, it would be incorrect. Example:

> Q: Is it too dark in here?
>   A: No. If anything, it's too light!

It's somewhat similar to the phrase "on the contrary."

Comment: This isn't the same *if anything* the examples use, though.

Answer (score 0):

It means that your not absolutely one thing or another but if you had to categorize or choose an option the * is the nearest option you'd describe yourself. Perhaps the degree to which you affiliate. E.g. my favourite colour is an extremely dark grey, I'd say black if anything.

Answer (score 0):

*If anything* is used to suggest tentatively that something may be the case (often the opposite of something previously implied).

> I haven't made much of this—if anything, I've played it down.